# Fill a javascript array from a php array and modify it by using checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Based on my post [checkbox unchecked var value 0 checkbox checked var value 1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62370371/edit)
where livello begins with 000..000 as all checkbox are unchecked and change state as a checkbox is checked, for example: 010..111, now I want to do the edit part. In this part the livello string is read from the database. I want livello to show the livello values and change as checkboxes are checked or not. Then the value from livello need to be reconverted to php string to write its value on the database.

```
<div class="modal-body">                        
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="livello_u_l">Selezionare accessi per l'utente:</label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <?php 
            // read from database but for example
            $livello_u_l = '00011100011100011100011';
            $liv_u_l = '';
                                
            $sql_u_l = "SELECT id, posizione, nome
                        FROM user_livelli";                 
            $result_u_l = $conn->query($sql_u_l);
            $contatore  = 0;
            if ($result_u_l->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result_u_l->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $id_u_l = $row['id'];
                    $posizione_u_l = $row['posizione'];
                    $nome_u_l = $row['nome'];
                    
                    // check if checkboxes are checked or not
                    if (substr($livello_u_l, $contatore, 1) == 1){                                                          
                        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='nome_posiz_u_l[]' checked />" ." " .$nome_u_l ." ";
                        //$liv_u_l .= '1'; 
                        $liv_u_l[$contatore] = '1';
                    } else {
                        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='nome_posiz_u_l[]' unchecked />" ." " .$nome_u_l ." ";
                        //$liv_u_l .= '0';
                        $liv_u_l[$contatore] = '0';
                    }
                    $contatore += 1;                                                        
        ?>
            <div id='show_u_l' class='col-sm-12'></div>
        <?php
                }
            }                                   
            //echo $livello_u_l;
            //echo $liv_u_l;
            //echo '<br>';
            //print_r($liv_u_l);
        ?>
    </div>
                        
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="livello_u_l">Livello:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="livello_u_l" name="livello_u_l"> </div> 
    </div>
                            
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let oInput1=document.getElementById('livello_u_l');
        let oCol1=Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('.form-group > input[type="checkbox"]') );
        
        // the following line fill livello with all 0                   
        let livello_u_l=new Array( oCol1.length ).fill( '0', 0, oCol1.length );
        
        // I want something like this
        //let livello_u_l=new Array( oCol1.length ).fill( <?php echo json_encode($liv_u_l); ?> );
        oInput1.value=livello_u_l.join('');

        oCol1.forEach( (chk,index)=>{
            chk.addEventListener('change',function(e){
            livello_u_l.splice(index,1,this.checked ? '1':'0' );
            oInput1.value=livello_u_l.join('');                                 
            });
        })
    </script>   
                        
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update_utente"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Modifica</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> Annulla</button>
    </div>
```

The script must be modified first to see the livello value read from the data base and then to modify its value on checkbox changes. And at the end its value must be converted to php string to write it on the database.

[image]

I tried to modify the javascript to fill the array with the value read from the database without success or better the way commented, write 23 times the livello value and also when I change one or more checkbox state it add 0 or 1 to the value and not modify it

---

The problem should be in the following line.

```
let livello_u_l=new Array( oCol1.length ).fill( '0', 0, oCol1.length );
```

Instead of fill livello with all 0  I want something like this

```
let livello_u_l=new Array( oCol1.length ).fill( <?php echo json_encode($liv_u_l); ?> );
    oInput1.value=livello_u_l.join('');
```

fill livello with `$livello_u_l = '00011100011100011100011';`

Comment: Please go read [ask]. So far, you have only given us a description of what you _want_ - that is not an appropriate way to ask here (this site is not a code-writing service.) You need to explain what you have actually tried so far, and give us a proper description of what problems you ran into with that.

Comment: And if your previous post contains relevant information, you should include that info in the question instead of linking us away, asking us to read other questions just to understand this one. Every question needs to have all needed information in it.